# Ruby regex: union 2K values in one regex,

Tags: ruby, regex

I code a process to process bunch of text files and capture its name if any of 2000 literals exists in it (1 or many).  So I'm thinking to combine that many values into one regex, do you think it's doable, I did test for 100 and looks like it's OK.  Tx all 
Code below depics my flow and sample code, just without looping.

```
# 1. read regex value list as file [alpha,fox, delta]  # 2000 values
# 2. read file into s                 #5000 files
# 3. find if any of #1 values exists in each #2 file. *with regex tweaks to match format  dbname.dob.table

s = '1 dbName.dbo.ALPHA  2 DBNAME.bcd.ALPHA  3 dbName..ALPHA   4 ALPHA 5x dbName.alphA  6x  alpha.XX  7x ###dbName.###a.alpha  --alpha
       dbName..FOX  dbName.dbo.DELTA    clarity.aba..fox  '

value1 = '(?<=^|\s)(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:alpha)(?=\s|$)'
value2 = '(?<=^|\s)(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:fox)(?=\s|$)'
##...
value2000 = '(?<=^|\s)(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:delta)(?=\s|$)'

regex = /#{value1}|#{value2}|#{value2000}/i           ## can I union 2000 regex's ???
puts 'reg1: ' + regex.to_s
puts 'result: ' + s.scan(regex).to_s
if s.scan(regex)  then  puts '...Match!!!d' end
```

Comment: Maybe you *could*, but given the `value`s in the question, it would probably be better to alternate only inside that non-capturing group there? (keep the regex DRY) End up with `(?:alpha|fox|foo|bar|.....|baz|delta)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring 2000 variables is highly unnecessary; you should define all values in a single array, then somehow loop through them.

Also, the regular expression is highly repetitive - e.g. the use of `(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)` 2000 times. This can be simplified by grouping all of your values within the non-capture group as follows:

```
values = %w(alpha fox delta)
regex = /(?<=^|\s)(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:#{Regexp.union(values)})(?=\s|$)/
```

This is the result:

```
/(?<=^|\s)(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)?(?:(?-mix:alpha|fox|delta))(?=\s|$)/
```

If you extend that `values` array to contain 2000 strings, the other code does not need to change.

Comment: Tx much CerPerf and Mr. Lord for your hints. I have real 2000 totally different vars I need to search for, they just prefixed by common <dbname>. Never though about `combining in non-capture groups`.

Comment: You might have 2000 *values*, but there's no need to declare 2000 *variables* :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided two conditions are met, I would do it as follows, which I think would be far more efficient than using a gigantic regular expression, which, by its nature, requires that a linear search of the "bad words" be performed for each word in the string, until a match is found or it is determined that there are no matches.

We are given a file whose path is contained in a variable `fname` and an array of bad words:

```
arr = ["alpha", "fox", "delta", "charlie", "mabel"]
```

The first condition that I spoke of above is that, by way of example, `"ALPHA"` and `"Alpha"` match `"alpha"`, but `"aLPha"` does not (or some variant of that).

The second condition is that there is a regular expression with a capture group that would capture a bad word if a bad word were present at the given location in a match. For example:

```
regex = (?<=^|\s)(?:dbName\.[a-z]*\.)?(\p{Alpha}+)(?=\s|$)
```

Wherever there is a match, the capture group `(\p{Alpha}+)` would capture a string of one or more alphanumeric characters whose value is assigned to the global variable `$1`. We will then check to see if the value of `$1` is a bad word. (The regular expression might have other capture groups as well, in which case we might be looking for `$2` or `$3`, say, or a named capture group.)

If there were more than one such regular expression to check for, the code below could be executed for each of them until a match is found or it is determined that there are no more matches.

The first step is to convert the array of bad words to a set:

```
require 'set'

bad_words = arr.flat_map { |w| [w, w.capitalize, w.upcase] }.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"alpha", "Alpha", "ALPHA", "fox", "Fox", "FOX",
  #           "delta", "Delta", "DELTA", "charlie", "Charlie", "CHARLIE",
  #           "mabel", "Mabel", "MABEL"}>
```

This allows very fast word lookups--much faster than stepping through an array. We may then search the file as follows.

```
rv = IO.foreach(fname).any? do |line|
  line.gsub(regex).any? { bad_words.include?($1) }
end
```

[IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) without a block is seen to return an enumerator. We can then chain that to `any?` to determine if there is a line that contains a match of the regular expression and the value of its capture group is contained in the set `bad_words`. If such a line is found the search terminates and `true` is returned; else, `false` is returned.

It is seen that [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) without a block returns an enumerator, which here I've chained to `any?`. This form of `gsub` has nothing to do with string replacements; it just generates matches. Those matches are passed to the block, but we are only interested in the contents of the capture group, which are held by `$1`. Hence the expression `bad_words.include?($1)`.